# Is there a way for message collectors to collect DMs in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to collect a user's reply to my bot's message, but all within DMs. How can I accomplish this task using the master branch of Discord.js (`12.0.0-dev`)?

I've tried to collect the message with pieces of code below:

```js
const collector = new MessageCollector(
  message.author.DMChannel,
  (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id,
  { max: 1, time: 120000 },
);
```

```js
const collector = message.author.dmChannel.createMessageCollector({
  max: 1,
  time: 120000,
});
```

This seems to be what I need, but I only want it to return the first message the user sends. When I `console.log()` the result, it's always `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a DM Channel, you can create a collector by using the `channel.createMessageCollector()` from `message.channel`

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content == `!collect`) {
    // Create a message collector
    const filter = m => (m.content.includes('discord') && m.author.id != client.user.id);
    const channel = message.channel;
    const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 10000 });
    console.log("collector started");
    collector.on('collect', m => console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`));
    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect a user's reply to your bot's message easily.

Use the DM Channel,
create a "collector" by using the

```
channel.createMessageCollector()
```

from

```
message.channel
```

Your code should match the given block:

```
client.on('xyz', message => {
  if (message.content == `!collect`) {
    const filter = m => (m.content.includes('media') && m.author.id != 
    client.user.id);
    const channel_xyz = message.channel;
    const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 10000 });
    console.log("collector started");
    collector.on('collected', m => console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`));
    collector.on('end', collected => console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} 
items`));
  }
 });
```